# luci.http.write_json escribir valores desde lua a html en OpenWrt

Tags: lua, embebido

estoy desarrollando "intentando" con OpenWrt un modulo que hace uso de luci y lua. Lo primero que me gustaría preguntar es si alguien conoce un tutorial bueno que no sea el básico de openwrt que solo te enseña entry y el sistema de ficheros.

Lo segundo es que estoy intentando escribir los datos de un fichero lua al html que referencia.

```
entry({"menganito", "menganito", "menganito"}, template("menganito-Module/menganito"), "menganito", 20).dependent=false

local redev = {
    id = 1,
    val = 1
}

local rv = {
        devval = redev
    }
luci.http.prepare_content("application/json")
luci.http.write_json(rv)
```

aquí se supone que carga el html menganito con esa url , eso lo hace correctamente, pero luego al intentar cargar los datos json me sale 
**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 27 of the JSON data**
Para leer los datos utilizo JS de la siguiente forma :

```
XHR.poll(5, '<%=REQUEST_URI%>', { status: 1 },
    function(x, info)
    {
        if (e = document.getElementById('id')){
            e.innerHTML = String.format('%t', info.devval.id);
        }

        if (e = document.getElementById('val')){
            e.innerHTML = String.format('%t', info.devval.val);
        }
        console.log(info);
    });
```

lo he sacado todo de los otros módulos puesto que no encuentro un tutorial ni documentación completa. este es el json sin procesar que genera :

```
{"devval":{"id":1,"val":1}}6~�w���w@N�w: 0
```

Si que parece que se envía pero luego da ese error (). No se si alguien puede echarme una mano o conoce alguna documentación que tenga contenido de calidad.

**PD: Si alguien con mas reputación puede generar la etiqueta luci, estaría bien :)**

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución que puede ser muy útil para muchos casos. y ya de paso explicarlo en español.

Lo primero y mas importante seguir el helloworld de luci [info](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/wiki/ModulesHowTo). Tras fulminarlo tendremos un archivo htm ojo htm no html y un .lua. La cosa de todo esto es que ta hacen entender que lo mejor es que el .lua realice el parser del htm, pero si lo que buscamos es por ejemplo leer un documento del servidor y escribir ese valor en el htm como es mi caso hay una forma mas fácil.

En [Wiki](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/wiki/Templates) nos ponen que si usamos la etiqueta <%=NombredeVariable%> en el htm podemos "*pasar de lua a htm*" , pero tiene que ser desde el mismo htm, es decir por ejemplo :

```
<% local variable = 0 -%>
<script type="text/javascript">console.log(<%=variable%>)</script>
```

Con este pequeño código podemos ver como <% -%> se ejecuta en el servidor y como cliente únicamente vemos la impresión del console.log.

**PD: Seria de gran ayuda si de todas formas alguien dispone de una forma de enviar los datos desde el .lua directamente, porque ahora me encuentro tratando de crear una llamada asíncrona que con el js pueda ir leyendo desde la parte del cliente**